# JAVA jdbc Eclipse SQLException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was trying to add details to table but it showing some SQL error

Query is:

```
t=st1.executeUpdate("insert into stdetails(regno,nam,cid,gender,HouseName,place,guardian,phone,photo,did,Emailid,sem) values("+  reg+",'"+ n +"',"+ c +",'"+g+"','"+ h+"','"+p+"','"+ guar +"','"+ph+"','"+pic+"',"+d+",'"+e+"',"+s+"");
```

Error is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line  1

Comment: Looks like one of your values is blank and you miss the single qoutes. BTW: learn about prepared Statements, to prevent SQL injection

Comment: But it is Also showing same error, when i use prepared stmnts

Comment: Please add the prepare stement to your question not as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing the parentheses **)** in the end of your query so it should look like :

```
t = st1.executeUpdate("...." + s + ")");
//----------------------------------^---
```

**BUT**

Instead of using this way, this can cause a syntax error like your case, and can cause an [Sql Injection](https://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection) you have to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: you are welcome, instead, i suggest to use PrepapredStatement ok to avoid all this problems of syntax ok @VaisakhMA

Answer (score 1):

there is error in your mysql syntax

```
 String query="insert into stdetails (regno,nam,gender) values(?,?,?)";
 PreparedStatement preparedStmt2 = con.prepareStatement(query);
 preparedStmt2.setInt (1," ");
 preparedStmt2.setString (2," ");
 preparedStmt2.setString(3, " ");
 preparedStmt2.execute();
```

like this you can add more columns also

Comment: Why setString if the first columns are int values

Comment: Can you really use a string in setInt?